# Ionic Build iOS and Xcode Build not deploying most Recent Ionic 2 Beta 10 build

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, git, ionic2

Ionic 2 beta 10 app, this worked fine in Beta 9.

1) `git pull` in terminal then run `ionic build ios`

2) Go to xcode and open the project connect my iphone to the computer and press run/build onto iphone

3) Shows up on iphone but it doesn't appear to be my most recent build and I have no idea why

My git version is the most recent. When I build in xcode should be the most recent, but seems to be older, major new elements and features are  not there.

In ionic app -> platforms -> ios -> app.xcodeproj it has the time and date of two days ago although I just ionic build ios and run/built in Xcode.

Same in platforms -> build  -> devices, it seems to not have the time and date of my most recent build of a few minutes ago.

Shouldn't the app.xcodeproj and the build in devices show the day/time of the latest build?

Been stuck on this for a awhile so any advice would be really helpful.

Comment: was your issue resolved?

Comment: I figured it out and wrote my answer below, very weird solution solved it. Thanks for your help and answering my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

Apparently, although ionic@beta is installed globally already, everytime I `git pull` I need to `npm install -g ionic@beta` for it to build the most recent build for iOS, otherwise will say build success but show me the older version.

It doesn't make sense to me since it was already installed globally. I also hope it won't mess things up in my app constantly installing it over and over before builds? But, it works.

Answer (score 4):

You probably only need to recompile your ios project. Simply:

```
$ionic state restore
```

This will remove all platforms and plugins and reinstall them. Then you can try again with

```
$ionic build ios
```

A more manual approach would be to:

```
$ionic platform rm ios
$ionic platform add ios
$ionic build ios
```

And then try again.

Clarification:

App.xcodeproj is not constantly recreated when building your app. The code compiled in your xcode project is, but not the proyect itself. This is created when you

```
$ionic platform add ios
```

So every time you run

```
$ionic build ios
```

You're basically changing the files inside the proyect, not deleting and recreating a new project each time.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. I tried removing and adding ios. I also tried ionic state restore. The output of ionic build ios for both is "build succeeded". I then went to xcode, reran the project onto iphone in both cases, it loaded fine, got in and it still isn't the newest build b/c there are elements/features I added that don't show up still. Also in project -> platforms -> build it got rid of the devices folder for some reason? Any other ideas why I can't get the most recent? Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem you might be facing is silent discarding of typescript compile errors. As for `ionic-gulp-browserify-typescript` version greater than `1.1.0` it is no longer accepting compile errors. The solution/workaround is to downgrade `ionic-gulp-browserify-typescript` in `package.json` with:

`npm install ionic-gulp-browserify-typescript@1.1.0 --save-dev`

more info here: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-2-not-generating-app-bundle-js/55640/19

Answer (score 0):

@Henry Ollarves answer is perfectly fine but he answered in 2016. now these commands have been changed. new commands are

```
$ionic cordova platform rm ios
$ionic cordova platform add ios
$ionic cordova build ios --prod --release
```