# ionic2 changes made in typescript or html files does not reflecting in browser or in build?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

When I made changes in typescript files OR any changes in HTML files it does not reflect over browser or in build.

It seems like it is not compiling code or what ..?

Comment: definitely more details are required like how you're invoking build process, what are the logs etc, as there may be plenty reasons. Usually trying to isolate a problem helps solving it

Comment: 'ionic serve' is the command I'm running every time, and day before it was working. I just updated to JDK1.8 and it stopped working!!

Comment: Actually, changes making in 'app/pages/html' files is not reflecting in 'www/build/pages/html' files.

If I made changes directly to 'www/build/pages/html' files it displayed everything.

Is it not compiling/building changes..?

Comment: I doubt that JDK update could broke ionic as ionic does not use java in any way. You may have a look on my other answer to a similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38555823/3021889

Comment: other place to look an answer is http://forum.ionicframework.com yet please do attach at least some logs produced by `ionic serve` as well as the output of `ionic info`

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed Problem**
by updating to latest IONIC CLI.

npm install -g ionic@beta